# Add a searchbox to a dropdown Wordpress

Tags: html, css, wordpress, woocommerce

I'm using Woocommerce and have edited the Towns/Cities checkout form to include a dropdown of 500 towns and cities that I need users to choose from. How do I implement a searchbox, so that they are able to search for their town?

Basically, how do I create something like this:
[image: Example]

for this:
[image: example]

I'm customising that field in Woocommerce, using the following code

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_default_address_fields' , 'customize_checkout_city_field' );
function customize_checkout_city_field( $address_fields ) {

    // Set HERE the cities (one line by city)
    $towns_cities_arr = array(
        '0' => __('Select your city', 'my_theme_slug'),
        'paris' => 'Paris',
        'versailles' => 'Versailles',
        'cannes' => 'Cannes',
    );

    // Customizing 'billing_city' field
    $address_fields['city']['type'] = 'select';
    $address_fields['city']['class'] = array('form-row-last', 'my-custom-class'); // your class here
    $address_fields['city']['label'] = __('Town / city', 'my_theme_slug');
    $address_fields['city']['options'] = $towns_cities_arr;


    // Returning Checkout customized fields
    return $address_fields;

}
```

Comment: Do you have any sample code for us to look at?

Comment: @CodeApprentice added the relevant code that generates that form field

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This plugin you want to use is Select2
https://select2.github.io/examples.html

You already have the custom class on your field called my-custom-class

All you need to do is import the select2 libs. You can do this in your theme functions.php.

```
function mytheme_enqueue_custom_scripts() {

    wp_enqueue_style( 'select2-css', 'https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.3/css/select2.min.css' );

    wp_enqueue_script( 'select2-js', 'https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.3/js/select2.min.js' );

}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'mytheme_enqueue_custom_scripts' );
```

And then add some jQuery to initialize it.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    jQuery(document).ready(function( $ ) {
      $(".my-custom-class").select2();
    });

</script>
```

Comment: Woocommerce seems to already include select2, I believe that's what they use for the Country field. The surpisingly tricky part was getting the class to be added to the right element (still don't know what the right one is) whatever, the above added the correct class but it didn't make the dropdown searchable, what I ended up doing was simply setting the class to `select` (in the jquery script) which was already set by woocommerce on the dropdown. Doing it that way worked for me.